# Installation error installing APK

Tags: android, react-native

I have generated an APK based on the [React-Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#docsNav).

When I try to install the APK I get "installation error" on my device and the app can not run. Why would an APK not install? Is there another method to generate an APK? I am building on Windows, please I need some help. Urgengly.

Comment: Try [this example APK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQY3qdmJQg-NkN4Rl9XV2FGWWs/view)

Comment: You are giving to me your apk to install? what your apk do?

Comment: It's not mine, but an example for a charting library. Just to see if it's your APK causing issues or not.

Comment: I will try in simulator

Comment: @MattyK14 your APK Works. What i have to do to make it work on my?

Comment: Please, I need Help Urgengly.

Comment: Your app show a yellow message on debug mode?

Comment: No. i can't even install the App. a generate the APK but i can not install

Comment: Can you run it in debug?

Comment: I Can't beacuse When I run the app on simulator, it can not be installed

Comment: @MattyK14 you have give to me an example APK. can you provide de file build.gradle because I want to know something like this: 


***defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.feetit"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }***

Comment: @BráulioJoelson [charts repo](https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper)

Comment: @MattyK14. I want to know how you generate the APK for your app to make it work